# PostgreSQL, pg_stat_all_tables.n_tup_XX

Tags: postgresql

I've been trying to get information about the number of inserts, updates and deletes on a table. I found the pg_stat_all_tables view and n_tup_ins/upd/del columns. These will tell me how many rows have been added to a table, but I can't find information about these values anywhere. I know they are all really collected from function

```
pg_stat_get_tuples_inserted(c.oid) AS n_tup_ins, 
pg_stat_get_tuples_updated(c.oid) AS n_tup_upd, 
pg_stat_get_tuples_deleted(c.oid) AS n_tup_del
```

The question is, what resets these values in runtime?
( If ever done ... )

Any ideas? Or am I looking in the wrong place?

Cheers
/P

Answer (score 1):

Use `pg_stat_reset()` to reset them, see the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/monitoring-stats.html).

For example

```
$ psql -Umyuser mydb
mydb# SELECT pg_stat_reset();
```

Comment: Ah, I was a bit unclear. The question was not so much how I reset it myself. It's more if any autoamtic operations within postgresql can reset these values (e.g autovacuum or autoanalyze ).

Comment: @peitur: Nothing resets these values automatically.

Comment: @Peter, if you can point us to a point in the documentation that gives such an evidence - that would be really nice.

Comment: I don't think it is documented that something doesn't happen.

Comment: Hi, I made an assumption, "counters" are usually reset sooner or later or by some actions. The question was more about the presence of a automatic reset of the "counters" mentioned. Was really hoping for an automatic reset, e.g. on analyze or vacuum.

Comment: @peitur Just observed in PostgreSQL 9.3 that `kill -9` of the postmaster process, or an `immediate` shutdown, causes a reset of these values.  That may be a bug.  I don't know what the side effects of that behavior would be.